# MySQL not running after upgrade to OS X El Capitan

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks

Due to unforeseen circumstances, I was forced to upgrade to OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

During the migration, I've managed to keep the databases for MySQL, and it appears to be the same version I had with Mavericks (mysql-5.6.14-osx10.7-x86_64).

However, when I go to the Preference Pane for MySQL in the System Preferences, I'm told "The MySQL server instance is not running" and the start button is disabled.

I've done various searches and either the suggestions don't seem to match the specific problem I'm having, or I'm not confident enough to try them in case I make things worse.

I've had a look in the "my.cnf" file and the settings are commented out and have blank values (a series of placeholder dots).

Also, the alias to the MySQL folder "mysql" is gone.

Needless to say I'm not that proficient on the command line.

Comment: How did you install MySQL initially? Via .pkg from the MySQL Downloads or using brew/macports?

Comment: It would have been as a package.